# Why dotnet test project.csproj --filter category=unit fails in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, xunit, xunit.net

I have my solution which is built in Azure DevOps. Since the solution has unit and integration tests I need to do filtering to avoid always editing the build definition. On my laptop the following command just runs fine and executes only the tests I need.

```
dotnet test project.csproj --filter Category=Unit
```

However, it fails in Azure DevOps with the following message.

```
[command]/usr/bin/dotnet test --filter Category=Unit {...}/{...}.Tests.csproj --configuration Release
No executable found matching command "dotnet-test --filter Category=Unit"
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/dotnet failed with return code: 1
```

The test projects have the following nuget packages:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="5.6.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="8.2.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="2.9.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.2.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.analyzers" Version="0.10.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.console" Version="2.4.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Build setup:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a **custom command**, just update the `Command` field to `Test` and move the argument flag for filtering to `Arguments`:

[image]