# DevOps Pipeline build .Net Core Test Category

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-pipelines

We have lots of tests in our projects which we have categorized as:

```
 [Test]
 [Category("UnitTest")]
 public void DoSomething()
 {
```

I can't figure out how to get the category to run on DevOps. In VS Test this was straight forward but we have to use a .Net Core test Task:

(This fails)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So after I searched on here and then post a question, I find the solution on here:

[Why dotnet test project.csproj --filter category=unit fails in Azure DevOps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701535/why-dotnet-test-project-csproj-filter-category-unit-fails-in-azure-devops)

--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --filter Category=UnitTest