# Dotnet test '--filter' is not recognized on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

ALM on Azure DevOps 2019

Projet in .NET 5

langage C#

Issue on task 5

---

**My goal** is to exclude an integration test which is mixed with unit tests, and which therefore fails my pipeline

on local the `dotnet test --filter FullyQualifiedName!=myProjet /p:CollectCoverage=true --configuration Release` work well, but not in my pipeline

a have this:
[image]

I install yet .NET 5 in a previous task, but nothing to do it does not want to recognize my `filter` arguments, `configuration`.

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build 
    steps:

    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
      inputs:
        packageType: sdk
        version: 5.x
        installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Restore dependencies
      inputs:
        command: restore
        projects: "**/*.csproj"
        arguments: --configfile nuget.config -v detailed
        feedsToUse: select
        vstsFeed: $(ARTIFACTS_FEED_NAME)
        includeNuGetOrg: false

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        command: build
        projects: "**/*.sln"
        workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
        arguments: --no-restore --configuration $(BUILD_CONFIGURATION) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(BUILD_CONFIGURATION)"
        zipAfterPublish: false
        modifyOutputPath: true

    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: Coverage
      inputs:
        script: "dotnet test \n--filter FullyQualifiedName!=wkf.WorkflowInvestorNotices.Test.Service.FileImportTest.GivenCompareExcelFileWhenReadCellsThenReturnResults\n--no-restore\n--configuration $(BUILD_CONFIGURATION)\n/p:CollectCoverage=true\n"
        workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/wkf.WorkflowInvestorNotices
```

Do you have any idea for my pipeline to recognize these arguments?

Comment: How about the result when you use dotnet test task instead of the command line task: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55701535/why-dotnet-test-project-csproj-filter-category-unit-fails-in-azure-devops

Comment: I already tried with the dotnetcorecli @ 2 task.
Indeed my filter argument works well.

But I have the impression that there is still a problem because I do not get the code cover board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Dotnet test '--filter' is not recognized on Azure DevOps

You could use `--filter` with the dotnet test task instead of the command line task:

[image]

For the issue in your comment, you do not get the code cover board. Please check if you enable the option **Publish test results and code coverage** in that task.

If that not help you, please share the build log in your question.